# Using Redmine Rest API to access Issues with criteria

Tags: rest, redmine

I am trying to run some statistics on issues in redmine related to specific projects and specific sprints. I have been reading about the Redmine Rest API to get the values for all issues (in Java, C# etc.) and have not found any way to take out specific issues with a specific criteria.

What I want to do (either I can do it via the API or simply via getting a json-object and querying it) is to extract all issues that have a specified project-value AND a specified fixed_version-value.

Using either the API or the JSON (`http://url/issues.json`) I cannot write a specific query enough to only take out the issues related to the specified values, nor can I extract more than 100 values at a time.

Is there a way to access the values without having to go through all of the issues (7500+) and checking against these values using the Rest API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To list issues of a project with specified version, use this:

```
GET /projects/[project id]/issues.json?set_filter=1&fixed_version_id=[fixed version id]
```

You can add a `limit` parameter to increase amount of returned issues, but only to the highest available limit set in administration.

You can use `page` parameter for pagination. Total count of issues matching current filter, current offset and limit are returned in each response.

Comment: As far as I could remember I tried to specify the fixed_version_id without result. But now it seems that it is working :)

Comment: It seems fixed_version_id filter only works when you use the URL /projects/[project id]/issues.json, not when using /issues.json directly.